# Split list into a row of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing

I have an image that I can read in via `imageio.imread()`. However, for simplicity's sake, let's say I have a list of `[1,2,3,4]`.

I'd like to transform that list into a dataframe of columns, represented as

```
   pixel_1  pixel_2  pixel_3  pixel_4
0        1        2        3        4
```

(The column names are not of vital importance; I just want to spread the data across columns.)

I've tried various `apply` and `map` methods but I'm just not sure how to read an image via `imageio.imread()` into a column spread like this.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]]).add_prefix("pixel_1")`

Comment: @anky This creates four rows in a single column called `pixel_1`, not a column for each number in the list along a single row.

Comment: It gives 1 row not four, may be you are using `pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])` instead of `pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]])` note the list of list vs using a single list in my comment

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check if below lines are helpful

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Blank Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
input_list = [1,2,3,4]
header_value ='Pixcel'

for item in input_list:

    df[header_value+"_"+str(item)]=[item]
# Out of loop
print(df)
```